# log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure() takes too long

Tags: asp.net-mvc, log4net, unity-container, log4net-configuration

I use Log4Net for logging. When the application starts, I call

log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

But this line takes 15 seconds to finish. Am I doing something wrong? Or is it normal?

I am developing with ASP.NET MVC, an use Unity for dependency injection.

At the application start, I call a Bootstrapper Initialise function

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    IUnityContainer container = Bootstrapper.Initialise();
    ...
    ...
}
```

In the Bootstrapper Initialize function, I register the type ILog.

```
private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    ...
    ...
    container.RegisterType<ILog>("", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
        new InjectionFactory(factory =>
        LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(HomeController).Assembly, connectionString)));
    ...
    ...
}
```

At the beginning of GetLogger function I call the configure function

```
public static ILog GetLogger(Assembly assembly, string connectionString)
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();  //<----- it takes 15 seconds to finish
    ...
    ...
}
```

**EDIT

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="0" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionString value="data source=[database server];initial catalog=[database name];integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=[user];Password=[password]" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception],[UserId],[Operation],[EntityType],[EntityId],[IP],[Host],[SessionId],[LogGroup]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception, @UserId, @Operation, @EntityType, @EntityId, @IP, @Host, @SessionId, @LogGroup)" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date" />
      <dbType value="DateTime" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@thread" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_level" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@logger" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@message" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="4000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@exception" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="2000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@UserId"/>
      <dbType value="Int32" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
        <key value="UserId" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@IP"/>
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="25" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
        <key value="IP" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@Host"/>
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
        <key value="Host" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@LogGroup"/>
      <dbType value="Int32" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
        <key value="LogGroup" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@Operation"/>
      <dbType value="Int32" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
        <key value="Operation" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@EntityType"/>
      <dbType value="Int32" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
        <key value="EntityType" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@EntityId"/>
      <dbType value="Int32" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
        <key value="EntityId" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@SessionId"/>
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="88" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
        <key value="SessionId" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: pause your application when it is half way thru (say 7 seconds of the 15 total) and look at the stack trace (of all threads if the main thread is waiting) to see what its waiting on or doing.

Comment: I tried your advice but it didnot help. Process waits there, and I think it does something internal.

Comment: Can you show us your configuration file?

Comment: Please see config above.

Comment: `Process waits there, and I think it does something internal.`
what is it doing? what is the stack showing? right click the call stack and select 'Show External Code' to get a better picture of where its stuck. are you running everything locally or is any component tied to a machine on the network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

15 Seconds sounds like a (connection) timeout, I believe the default timeout is 15 seconds.

I had a similar problem once and it turned out to be The CLR tried to verify the authenticode signature at load time to create publisher evidence for an assembly.
I am not sure about the details but there is a configuration element named "generatePublisherEvidence" in the assembly section where it can be turned off. You should check if you want to do this though. And what the implications for this are. 
If you are using .Net 4 (or greater) this should have no impact on load time.

For web applications this setting cannot be set in the applications web.config. It should be set in the aspnet.config in the .Net framework directory.

Comment: It takes not exactly 15 seconds, but 14,3 something. I think it is not the timeout. Although, as you guessed, I use .Net 4, I tried "generatePublisherEvidence" configuration but it didnot help, either.

Comment: A note to this is that if you have configured a database appender in your configuration file, log4net will try to connect even if you are not using that appender.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to call the following statement

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

The system will try to validate the given database connection string. Here the problem is, your given connection string might be not connecting and it is trying to connect until it's given a time out.

Please verify is your given connection string is valid or not.

http://techxposer.com/2017/08/08/log4net-config-xmlconfigurator-configure-taking-too-much-time/